# Passengers heard 'screaming' - who was doing the "hearing"?

Tags: past-tense

> Passengers heard 'screaming'

I feel this phrase could be interpreted in two ways:

1) The passengers could and did hear screaming (from someone else).
2) Someone else could and did hear the passengers screaming.

Which is correct?

Comment: Both constructions (without the quotation marks) could be correct, though (2) is more like "headline English": *Passengers Heard Screaming As Plane Crashes*.

Comment: @Matt Gutting Your headline fits the OP's category 1, and makes no sense at all. The passengers may well have heard the screams of others, but they were undoubtedly so terrified that the fact has little relevance. What *passengers heard screaming* refers to is thae fact that people listening to the cockpit voice recorder, heard passengers screaming.  (I'm glad I didn't have to listen to it).

Comment: It's ambiguous. You'd need further context to infer.

Comment: @WS2 As an exàmple, perhaps two passengers heard screaming which originated in the cockpit. This is case 1. Then someone else outside listening heard the passengers screaming. This is my headline, case 2.

Comment: I agree that without any context it could be interpreted either way.  As soon as you put it into the context of the GermanWings crash, however, only the second could possibly apply.

Comment: Give us a sentence, please. One cannot determine without any context. "Passengers heard screaming" might be a headline, but not a likely sentence.  "The passengers heard screaming " or  "Some passengers heard screaming" " or "Passengers were heard screaming" are unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

"The passengers heard screaming coming from the next compartment."

or

"it was revealed that the passengers heard screaming were merely startled by unexpected turbulence."

Both are correct interpretations if put into context, but as a phrase it is too ambiguous to definitively pair with either meaning.